# display complete new page with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have build a mobile app which shows a list of movies. Its a static for now. I want to implement a react router for routing. What i want is when user clicks on the TV Shows from the list, he/she should be directed to the detail page of that TV Show. Not on the same page(layout) where list contains. I tried to do that but when i click on the title of the TV Show i am directed nowhere. How can i do that so?The code might help for expert to know what i am wanting and where i am doing wrong.

Here is my code first

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
      <Route component={DetailLayout}>
        <Route name="flash" path="/flash" component={Flash} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

**MovieListItem.js(rendered by App.js)**

```
const MovieListItem = ({movie}) => {
  const imageUrl = movie.imageUrl;
  const mainCastJoin = _.join(movie.mainCast, ', ');
  return (<li className="list-group-item">
            <div className="video-list media">
              <div className="media-left">
                <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} alt={movie.title} />
              </div>
              <div className="media-body">
                <div className="media-heading">
                  <Link to="flash"><h4 className="title">{movie.title}</h4></Link>
                </div>
                <div className="main-cast">
                  <ul id="cast-list">
                      <li className="list-item">
                        {mainCastJoin}...
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="reviewer">
                  <img className="img-responsive reviewer-img" src={imdb} alt="{movie.title}" />
                  <div className="imdbScore">
                    {movie.imdb}
                  </div>
                  <img className="img-responsive reviewer-img" src={rottenTomatoes} alt="{movie.title}" />
                  <div style={{verticalAlign:'middle', display:'inline'}} className="rottenTomatoesScore">
                    {movie.rottenTomatoes}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      )
};

export default MovieListItem;
```

**Flash.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Flash extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Detail page of Flash will be shown here with different Layout as in second image i have attached</div>
    );
  }
}
```

**DetailLayout.js**

```
export default class DetailLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>MyComponent</div>
      );
  }
}
```

When title of TV Show is clicked, i want to show its detail page which has completely different layout.

**UPDATE**
I dont know how but this works

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
    </Route>
      <Route path="detail" component={DetailLayout}>
        <Route name="flash" path="/flash" component={Flash} />
      </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

In MovieListItem.js if i change  to  it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your `flash` route as a child of `DetailLayout` but it renders only `MyComponent` and has no children. Just include `{this.props.children}` in `DetailLayout`.

Set link in your MovieItemList as `<Link to="/flash>`

React router searches for all the routes and then renders the route it matches,and since we have added a `/flash` in the route it finds `flash` as child of `/` thats the reason it works.

You can also make it work by using `detail/flash` by handling the route inside flash as `<Route name="flash" path="/detail/flash" component={Flash} />`

```
export default class DetailLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div>MyComponent</div>
          <div>{this.props.children}</div>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Route

```
 ReactDOM.render((
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} >
          <Route name="detail" path="detail" component={DetailLayout}>
            <Route name="flash" path="/flash" component={Flash} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

MovieItem.js

```
 const MovieListItem = ({movie}) => {

  const imageUrl = movie.imageUrl;
  const mainCastJoin = _.join(movie.mainCast, ', ');
  return (<li className="list-group-item">
            <div className="video-list media">
              <div className="media-left">
                <img className="media-object" src={imageUrl} alt={movie.title} />
              </div>
              <div className="media-body">
                <div className="media-heading">
                  <Link to="flash"><h4 className="title">{movie.title}</h4></Link>
                </div>
                <div className="main-cast">
                  <ul id="cast-list">
                      <li className="list-item">
                        {mainCastJoin}...
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="reviewer">
                  <img className="img-responsive reviewer-img" src={imdb} alt="{movie.title}" />
                  <div className="imdbScore">
                    {movie.imdb}
                  </div>
                  <img className="img-responsive reviewer-img" src={rottenTomatoes} alt="{movie.title}" />
                  <div style={{verticalAlign:'middle', display:'inline'}} className="rottenTomatoesScore">
                    {movie.rottenTomatoes}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      )
};

export default MovieListItem;
```

Comment: with that code i am getting this error. Warning: [react-router] Location "/detail/flash" did not match any routes

Comment: Change `<Link to="/detail/flash"> `to `<Link to="detail/flash">`

Comment: Tried that too and got similar error detail/flash did not match any routes.

Comment: @Learner try and change /flash to flash in the route handler and also you can check only <Link to="detail"> and see if it works.

Comment: I have updated my question with bizarre solution. Can you please make me understand, how is that working? link should be i think /detail/flash but /flash makes it work.

Comment: React router searches for all the routes and then renders the route it matches,and since you have added a /flash it find flash as child of `/`  thats the reason it works.  You can also make it work by using detail/flash by handling the route inside flash as <Route name="flash" path="/detail/flash" component={Flash} />

Comment: Can you please edit your solution so i can mark it as answered? Please do explain in the solution too as it might help other.

Comment: @Learner Just did that.

Comment: I think route should also be changed. Flash route inside / route is not working. I tried with all the link but it did not work. The route code that i posted in my question is only working. To make detail/flash work i have to change <Route name="flash" path="/flash" component={Flash} /> to <Route name="flash" path="flash" component={Flash} />.

Comment: I will check this issue and then get back to it. Presently I don't have nodejs set up in my laptop. Will get back to you with a proper solution later. Till then you can use the same :)

Comment: I understand your explanation, though. With your explanation i could make detail/flash work but could not understand why /flash is not working inside / route. Thanks for clear explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124371/discussion-between-learner-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: You can accept the answer now. I will work on the current problem in the evening